# Using a dictionary to create system log in

Tags: python, dictionary, authentication

I have a whole system created and I just want the users to have to have a username and password to access the system. 
This is the code i have written to add the username and password to the saved dictionary, but everytime i run this is just overwrites whatever is in the store.

`username=input("What would you like the username to be?")
 password=input("What would you like the password to be?")
newperson = {username,password}
pickle.dump(newperson, open("Userstore","wb"))`

how would i code it to keep the information already stored in "Userstore" and add the newperson to the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following logic:
check if Userstore present, if it present then read the already saved data.

Code:

```
import pickle
import os
filename = "Userstore"
userdict = {}
if os.path.isfile(filename):
    userdict = pickle.load(open(filename, "rb"))
username = input("What would you like the username to be?")
password = input("What would you like the password to be?")
userdict[username] = password
print userdict
pickle.dump(userdict, open("Userstore", "wb"))
```